# bytes to human readable string

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am using the following code to convert bytes to human readable file size. But
it's not giving accurate result.

```
public static class FileSizeHelper
{
    static readonly string[] SizeSuffixes = { "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };
    public static string GetHumanReadableFileSize(Int64 value)
    {
        if (value < 0) { return "-" + GetHumanReadableFileSize(-value); }
        if (value == 0) { return "0.0 bytes"; }

        int mag = (int)Math.Log(value, 1024);
        decimal adjustedSize = (decimal)value / (1L << (mag * 10));

        return string.Format("{0:n2} {1}", adjustedSize, SizeSuffixes[mag]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
FileSizeHelper.GetHumanReadableFileSize(63861073920);
```

It returns `59.48 GB`
But if I convert the same bytes using google converter it gives `63.8GB`.
Any idea what is wrong in the code?

Goolge screenshot:

[image: Google screenshot]

@René Vogt and @bashis thanks for explanation. finally get it working using following code

```
public static class FileSizeHelper
{
    static readonly string[] SizeSuffixes = { "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };
     const long byteConversion = 1000;
    public static string GetHumanReadableFileSize(long value)
    {

        if (value < 0) { return "-" + GetHumanReadableFileSize(-value); }
        if (value == 0) { return "0.0 bytes"; }

        int mag = (int)Math.Log(value, byteConversion);
        double adjustedSize = (value / Math.Pow(1000, mag));


        return string.Format("{0:n2} {1}", adjustedSize, SizeSuffixes[mag]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `63861073920 bytes to gib`

Comment: Note that your result matches google's Gibibyte option - this is one of the issues in this area, differing opinions of whether  Giga/mega is 1000 or 1024 etc.

Comment: You're dividing by `1024` and google obviously by `1000`

Comment: Regardless of the difference between `gibi` or `giga`, please don't use `(int)Math.Log(value, 1024)`. It might mathematically be correct, but computationally it could introduce errors that you don't want. A simple rounding error could change the result by ±1.

Comment: dear all thankyou very much for explanation actually client need that format so updated the code to get google like results. .:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always a little confusion about how to display bytes. Your code is correct if the result is what you are trying to achieve.

What you showed from Google is a decimal representation. So just as you say `1000m = 1km`, you can say `1000byte = 1kB`.

On the other hand, there is the binary representation where `1k = 2^10 = 1024`. These representations are called [kibiBytes, Gibibytes etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte).

Which representation you choose is up to you or the requirements of your customers. Just make obvious which you use to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your results are correct if you expect to receive [gibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte). Google, however, returns you [gigabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte).

The difference is that provided `x` bytes you get `x / (1000 * 1000 * 1000)` gigabytes and `x / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)` gibibytes.